# Windows factory reset with a Linux partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, reset

I installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10 in a partition, so I can use both in my laptop. My question is, if I use the Windows factory reset on my Windows partition, will that erase my Linux partition?

*Edit*: The factory reset did not erase the Linux partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hardware manufacturer's factory reset will reset your laptop back to the original state that it was when it was shipped from the factory with Windows preinstalled. It will erase everything else including your Linux partition.

A Windows factory reset which is initiated from Windows will not erase the Linux partition. You can select either the *Keep my files* or *Remove everything* options depending on whether you want to keep your data files intact. Either way, all of your Windows settings will return to their defaults and apps will be uninstalled.

Comment: It will erase the GRUB (that "choose the OS you want to boot now" screen) i currently see when i start my laptop ? Or it will malfunction ? 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Windows factory reset will erase GRUB bootloader and replace it with the original Windows bootloader that your laptop had when it was shipped from the factory.

Comment: Well then, thanks again for your help. I'll edit the OP if something goes wrong with that factory reset.